# How I can find the email based on google plus id?

Tags: google-plus

Based on a url like

https://plus.google.com/123456789012345678901 # dummy number

How I can find the gmail username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing an app or script, you can use Oauth 2.0 and request the userinfo.email scope.

For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836385/1354939

This does require that you configure a [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) project and create a OAuth 2.0 client ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. For privacy reasons, having someone in a circle or knowing their Google Plus id should not be enough to get an email address.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible to find an arbitrary user's email address solely from the id contained in such a [Google+](https://plus.google.com/112496876295536846823) URL.